# embed images as base64 instead of outputing to folder

Tags: c#, docx4j, docx4j.net

When converting from docx to html you may specify the output path for any images

```
org.docx4j.Docx4J.toHTML(wordMLPackage, imageDirPath, imageTargetUri, fos2);
```

and the resulting html document references images via files:

```
<img height="22" id="rId7" src="..cc6bcedf-2770-45ad-8e81-610bbd8746ceimage1.png" width="42">
```

Instead I would like the converter to embed the files as base64. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure you can, but its bad form. It would use a lot more bandwidth.

Comment: @Aron i am rendering the html serverside then returning it back on the wire to the client (a winforms app) which then shows it in a `WebBrowser` control - I dont want to have to send the images separately and then deal with saving them on the client side

Comment: You mean you are implementing a custom web browser... That only works on one web site.

Comment: @Aron I dont understand. 'only works on one web site' - no i am not implementing a custom web browser

Comment: Yes you are. It's a html renderer working on a custom protocol to display HTML generated by the server. Why don't you just use HTTP?

Comment: how would i 'just use HTTP' < -- i'm in winforms where the app talks over WCF (all binary endpoints) - explain to me since you know my problem better than i do how i'm going to display that in a winforms app? and i want to render it in html so it can be consumed by another application which IS a website

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: a link to the `WebBrowser` control ?? like i mentioned in my first comment?

Comment: Just say the URL on the control then.

Comment: can't work like that. can't just be a public URL needs to be secured by credentials and the user already 'logged in' to the winforms app so not going to do it again. you dont know the problem space you made some gross assumptions

Comment: My assumption is you are reinventing the square wheel. Which you are. Tunnel the connection if you have to...

Comment: Doesn't make me wrong.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JT9I1fPmMJg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a custom `ConversionImageHandler` to achieve this. 
You can simply set imageDirPath to an empty string and the images will be embedded

```
org.docx4j.Docx4J.toHTML(wordMLPackage, "", "", fos2);
```

This occurs because `org.docx4j.model.images.AbstractConversionImageHandler` (from which `HTMLConversionImageHandler` derives) already handles this case for you .

Comment: Glad you noticed that :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own ConversionImageHandler implementation to do that.

The default implementation HTMLConversionImageHandler writes images to files.

To use your image handler, specify it via htmlSettings.setImageHandler

Comment: Jason thanks I was able to find a solution off the back of your answer after digging thru the source