# Docx4j: Embedding images in generated html from docx

Tags: java, docx4j

I'm working on my first project using docx4j...
following the example at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-samples-docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertOutHtml.java I get an html file with the images linked to an external directory. is it possible to embed images directly in the html file, in base64 form?
Also, there is a way to exclude image extraction from the docx to generated html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [embed images as base64 instead of outputing to folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794169/embed-images-as-base64-instead-of-outputing-to-folder) regarding base64.  In summary, this can be achieved by setting imageDirPath to an empty string.

To exclude image extraction entirely, implement ConversionImageHandler returning null.